# Android - How to run another app

Tags: android, spawn

I am interested in opening the Google Navigator app from inside an application I am writing.  I want to be able to spawn it at a given time and pass specific data into it.

Can anyone think of a good way for me to do this?  What permissions do I need, etc?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for intents. These are messages you throw up to the system that allow the appropriate action to be taken, such as opening another application.

[Here is a guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) to using Intents and Intent Filters.

In particular, [here is a page](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) that discusses the intents you should use for Google's applications, including Google Maps.

Also, [see here for a similar question](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/83d2803f799c6f5f?pli=1) asked on Google's forum.

A sample of example code that works is as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=New+York+NY)); 
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It's my pleasure. Don't forget to accept the best answer to your questions once you are satisfied with responses :)